# How to run long tasks in the background od django without pausing the execution of the app

Tags: django

I want to know how to run independently a very long task that takes probably 2 minutes in the backend of django. I used threading in python and it works but as soon as i execute another task in the main django project the task in the background stops and doesn't finish executing.
Celery and django background tasks have the same issue as well, i tried them and it didn't work.
So please if anyone has an idea how to do that, help me!!!!
thanks so much in advance

Comment: You can look into django redis queues, https://github.com/rq/django-rq

Comment: does django rq can make a task run without getting paused by running the main django views ???

Comment: Yes it does. The task is queued and ran in the background while not interrupting the view in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Celery has capability to run background task, and it don't overrides other task, i have used and it works perfectly fine, can you re check documentation of celery, you can also check on django-celery-beat for perodic task scheduling